# How to use Javascript .replace() method within a for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, replace

I am attempting to take a given string and replace a given number in that string with a character. Specifically:

- 5 is to be replaced with "S"
- 1 is to be replaced with "I"
- 0 is to be replaced with "O"

(this is a [Kata exercise](https://www.codewars.com/kata/577bd026df78c19bca0002c0/javascript))

I have written a function which should:

1. Take the string and convert it into an array
2. Loop over the array
3. Replace each instance of the aforementioned numbers with the appropriate replacements using .replace()
4. Return the joined string.

My code is as appears below

```
Function correct(string) {
let array = string.split('')
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i].replace('5', 'S')
    array[i].replace('0', 'O')
    array[i].replace('1', 'I')
  }
  return array.join('');
}
```

The function returns the string exactly as initially provided, unchanged. I suspect my issue is with the way I've used the `.replace()` method within the loop, or the index positions declared.

Comment: [`.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) _"returns a new string"_...

Comment: [`String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) doesn't work in place. You have to assign the result somewhere ...

Comment: Just use `String.prototype.replaceAll`, like `string.replaceAll('5', 'S').replaceAll('0', 'O')`

Comment: If you want your code to work, just assign a result of a replacement like so: `array[i] = array[i].replace('5', 'S');`. But I recomment using the solution from my previous comment.

Comment: You can also use a regualar expression for replacement `return string.replace(/5/g, 'S').replace(/0/g, 'O').replace(/1/g, 'I')`

Comment: @YuriyYakym Consider posting it as an answer so that I can mark it as correct. I did not assign a result of a replacement as you said. `array[i] = array[i].replace('5', 'S');` works.

Also, I am new to stackoverflow, is there something I could do to improve the question so that it may not be marked down? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.prototype.replace` returns a new string and does not mutate the variable it was executed on.
That's why you need to assign the result of replacement somewhere.

To fix your code just do the following with each replacement:

```js
array[i] = array[i].replace('5', 'S');
```

---

Note 1: since `array[i]` is always a single character, there is no need in `replace`, because you can just compare like so:

```js
if (array[i] === '5') {
  array[i] = 'S';
}
```

or oneliner:

```js
array[i] = array[i] === '5' ? 'S' : array[i];
```

Note 2: `for` loop for a replacement is not a clean code. JavaScript is very flexible and provides much better solutions to the problem. Eg. `String.prototype.replaceAll`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with simple regex `replace()` based on your key=>value like this,

```js
const key_to_replace = { 
    '5': 'S',
    '1': 'I',
    '0': 'O'
}

const correct = (str) => 
   str.replace(/./g, (m) => key_to_replace[m] ?? m);

console.log(correct("this 5is a0 test1 with 55abc"))
```

Comment: What is a purpose of string template literal?

Comment: This code does not work for more than one occurrence. For example for this string `55abc`.

Comment: I have a few correct solutions for this exercise. However, I was wondering whether one can loop over the array using the .replace() method specifically. If not, how come?

Comment: @ChristosBinos you can, see my second comment under you question.

Comment: @ChristosBinos it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this **:**

```js
const inputStr = 'AB5DE0G1H';

function correct(string) {
  return  string.replaceAll('5', 'S').replaceAll('0', 'O').replaceAll('1', 'l')
}

console.log(correct(inputStr));
```